# How to know if graphql returned an error when using curl?

Tags: shell, curl, graphql, http-error

HTTP GraphQl calls always return 200 - even if the response doesn't suite the request.

I'm trying to do a graphql call and understand if there's an error, like using `$?` and `--fail` but it doesn't help because of the always 200 response.

Even if graphql's output isn't according to input and contains error arrays, curl only cares about the http code, which is always 200.

Is there a way for curl to understand a graphql error? Like some kind of built in mechanism in to compare requested input to actual input and understand there's an error?

Perhaps I'm barking on the wrong tree here and should use some command line tool more dedicated to graphql? Thanks.

Comment: *"... should use some command line tool more dedicated to graphq?"* ... Yes, definitely. You're hoping for too much that a general command line tool could have built-in knowledge about a completely different knowledge domain (IMHO). Start with capturing the output to a file and then build reg exs that can flag an error and return an error code. You may be able to turn that into a pipeable function and avoid a tmp file. again, IMHO (-;! Good luck!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`curl` doesn't know anything in particular about GraphQL. You can pipe the output of curl to grep to check for the presence of errors and draw conclusions based on that as necessary.

ex:

```
curl --request POST \
    --header 'content-type: application/json' \
    --url http://localhost:4000/ \
    --data 'your query data'| grep "errors"
```